# How to create a dynamic html link in PHP

Tags: php, url, hyperlink

I tried to create a link from a piece of code such as below format:

```
<a href=(php code what is may be)> website </a>
```

The piece of PHP code that I want to create a link is:

```
echo $house->ownername, '</br>', $house->owneremail;
```

I want to get the *ownername* a url and the *owneremail* an email-url. Is this possible? And if so, how?

```
<div class="span3">
<?php positions_rem($params->get('view05')); ?>
<?php    if ($params->get('show_owner_line') ==1 && $params->get('show_owner_line') ==1) {
                ?>
   <div class="rem_house_contacts">
        <div id="rem_house_titlebox">
            <?php echo _REALESTATE_MANAGER_LABEL_CONTACT_AGENT ; ?>
        </div>    
                    <?php if (isset($house->agent) && trim($house->agent)) { ?>
                    <span class="col_02"><?php echo $house->agent; ?></span>
            <?php
            }
            ?>

                            <?php
            if ($params->get('show_owner_line') && $house->ownername != '' || $house->owneremail != '') {
                if ($params->get('show_owner_registrationlevel')) {
                    ?>
                    <span class="col_02"><?php echo $house->ownername, '</br>', $house->owneremail; ?></span>
                    <?php
                }
            }
                    ?>

                    <?php
            if ($params->get('show_contacts_line')) {
                if ($params->get('show_contacts_registrationlevel')) {
                    if (isset($house->contacts) && trim($house->contacts)) {
                        ?>
                    <span class="col_02"><?php echo $house->contacts; ?></span>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Hope someone can help me with it.

Comment: Updated title for precise concision and spelling/grammar for readability.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy to do

```
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $house->owneremail;?>">
    <?php echo $house->ownername;?>
</a>
```

Same technique can be used with normal links

Comment: ok thanks for email its working but not for a normal link I've added this code but the ownername is not shown as a link.<a href="<?php echo $house->ownername;?>">
    <?php echo $house->ownername;?>
</a><br/>
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $house->owneremail;?>">
    <?php echo $house->owneremail;?>
</a>

Comment: what is stored in `$house->ownername`? is it a full url?

Comment: You might have to add your path before the php tag... `<a href="/myscript?owner=<?php echo $house->ownername; ?>">...`